# Java application for downloading Imgur wallpapers from galleries

Tags: java, gradle

I'm fairly new to real world Java so I tried to rewrite an old app I wrote in vanilla java.  I've made this one a lot more OO and used a dependency/build manager (Gradle).  Now I just want to see what more experienced devs have to say about the project.

This is the main code snippet that does most of the work.  Any comments here are welcomed.

**src/pw/jor/imgurwallpaper/gui/Worker.java : 37**

```
// get url
selection= getGUISelection(selectedURLIndex++);
url = createURL(selection);

// get parser contents
body = Downloader.getPageContents(url);

// parse body for image hashes
ParserAbstract parser = getParser(selection);
parser.parse(body);

// write hashes to file
Writer.writeFiles(parser.getImageHashes());
```

[Entire project](https://github.com/platypusMaximus/ImgurWallpaper)

Comment: There's not much to review in this snippet. I suggest to include the entire file (possibly related files too)

Comment: The project's git repo is linked under the snippet

Comment: Unfortunately your question is off-topic as of now, as the code to be reviewed must be [present in the question.](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/1308) Code behind links is considered non-reviewable. Please add the code you want reviewed in your question. Thanks!

Comment: @BCdotWEB actually the code is properly included. It's only that the stuff behind the github link is not considered reviewable. I assume this code is present exactly that way in the Project, and it's just rather stripped of context. This doesn't mean there is no code present at all. As such I consider the question on-topic

Answer (score 4):

You are very very very procedural here. Java does allow this to some extent, but it feels rather clunky. Be aware that there's significant lack of context here, so I will have to make a few well-educated guesses in reviewing this code…

---

> ```
> selection = getGUISelection(selectedURLIndex++);
> ```

there's a few things wrong with this: The first thing for you to learn will be "Tell, don't ask".

Wherever this code is, you should be passing it the GUISelection through an `ActionListener` or similar by invoking the method with that already done. `selection` should be a parameter.

Actually… scratch that:

```
url = createURL(selection);
```

**this** should be the paraemter to the method we're in right now.

You need to get your responsibilities straight: one method does one thing. and it does that well…

---

Work on objects, avoid the static context if you can:

> ```
> body = Downloader.getPageContents(url);
> ```

this should be using an instance:

```
body = downloader.getPageContents(url);
```

Did I already mention you should declare variables as close as possible to their usage?

This looks like you fell prey to ages old convention to declare your variables at the top of your procedure. This makes code overly complex to follow for longer procedures and it's plain confusing.

```
String body = downloader.getPageContents(url);
```

would be better.

---

> ```
> ParserAbstract parser = getParser(selection);
> ```

again: Tell, don't ask. Additionally: work on objects. Creating a specific Parser for a selection is a separate responsibility. As much as I hate them, this is a use-case for a Factory:

```
ParserAbstract parser = ParserFactory.getParser(selection);
```

In addition to that, `ParserAbstract` sounds like an `abstract class`. I daresay it's probably better off as an `interface` instead, and if not: at least put the Abstract before the Parser. But I think the following is more idiomatic java:

```
Parser parser = ParserFactory.getOrCreateParser(selection);
```

---

> ```
> parser.parse(body);
>
> // write hashes to file
> Writer.writeFiles(parser.getImageHashes());
> ```

this seems like an anti-pattern to me. A parser usually is not stateful, iow. it should not keep the results of parsing somewhere, but just return them.

Also again: **Tell, don't ask**, and again you work on a Class instead of an instance with the Writer.

more idiomatic for java would be something like:

```
writer.writeFiles(parser.parse(body));
```

or a little more stretched out and explicit:

```
ParseResults imageHashes = parser.parse(body);
writer.writeFiles(imageHashes);
```

Comment: I've implemented the GUI passing the selection to the worker, a new Class for handling gallery type based on selection, converted the ParserAbstract to an interface, and created a Parser class that has a ParserInterface injected